# Angular 2 - load component from its own file, instead of on the module file

Tags: angular

In `Angular 2+`, you create `Components` and register them to `NgModule`, like this;

```
import { AppComponent1 } from 'app.component1';
import { AppComponent2 } from 'app.component2';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [ AppComponent1, AppComponent2 ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This works okay, I guess, for a tiny site. But what do you do when you have a large site? It's very cumbersome to try and put **every** module import in the same file.

Is there any way to add the component to the module in its own file? More like this?

```
import { AppModule } from '/app/module';

@Component({
   ...
})
export class AppComponent {}

AppModule.declarations.push(AppComponent);
```

or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`Feature Module`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#feature-modules).

Have a look at the documents and let me know if you needed an example.

Comment: Yeah, I'm reading over this and I just don't understand it. The example it gives doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Simple explanation: you can create child modules where you import you components into them and you import them into main module

Comment: That makes considerably more sense! Thank you!